# ImageMagick convert problem, command killed or silently exits

Tags: command-line, pdf, imagemagick

Im having peculiar problem with the "convert" command on Precise hosted on Linode. I am trying to convert a pdf to a memory persistent cache file *.mpc using the following command:

```
$ convert -density 300 infile.pdf infile.mpc
```

The original pdf is about 50MB and the resulting *.cache file is about 7GB. I then generate thumbnails etc using the mpc file.

Everything works fine on various different instances of Ubuntu Precise, my local vagrant box and our physical dev server. When I run this command on our Linode virtual host it doesn't work. I have monitored the memory/disk etc but everything looks fine. I have even set minimal limits but It still doesn't work. I can see the disk space decrease by about 7GB from the tmp files in /tmp so I know its almost done with processing, but then the disk space return to normal and im left with a tiny mpc file, 62mb instead of a few Gigabytes. I have tried passing debug params but  I dont get any error message, only sometimes I get "Killed"

To make this even more puzzling is that the command works when I changed the path of the output file to an NFS mount. If I change both the tmp and the destination directory to the NFS mount, it exits silently - they same if I put both destination and tmp directory on the local disk.

I have plenty of resources on the host so I am at a loss what the problem could be..

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of ImageMagick you're running? Please provide the output of `convert --version`?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...
(It sounds like a bug though.. Nothing in the log files neither? try `sudo tail -f /var/log/{kern.log,dmesg,syslog}` in one terminal and then running your command in another terminal